# jQuery select class outside "this"

Tags: jquery, class, select, jquery-animate

Okay so this is my set up

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="video-play-button"></div>
</a>
<img class="video-image" src="URL" alt="" />
<div class="video-underlay"></div>
```

The "video-play-button" is an overlay of the "video-image" which is 100% x 100% of the image and what I'm trying to do is when you hover the "video-play-button" it changes the opacity of the "video-image" which would then show the "video-underlay"

jQuery:

```
jQuery(".video-play-button").hover(
    function () {
        jQuery(".video-image").stop().animate({opacity: '0.7'}, 300);},
    function () {
        jQuery(".video-image").stop().animate({opacity: '1'}, 400);
});
```

This works but as I'm going to have multiple elements with the same code and classes it affects them all not each single one.

I'm new to js and jquery so I appolagise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside of [Adil's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17681356/1456376) answer, this should work as well:

```
jQuery(".video-play-button").parent().hover(
    function () {
        jQuery(this).next().stop().animate({opacity: '0.7'}, 300);},
    function () {
        jQuery(this).next().stop().animate({opacity: '1'}, 400);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the `hover` to current block, first find the parent `a` anchor tag using closest() and then move to sibling of anhor with class `video-image`

```
jQuery(".video-play-button").hover(
    function () {
        jQuery(this).closest('a').next(".video-image").stop().animate({opacity: '0.7'}, 300);},
    function () {
        jQuery(this).closest('a').next(".video-image").stop().animate({opacity: '1'}, 400);
});
```

Comment: Can you make a demo on jsFiddle.net?

Comment: no worries found a simple typo which when fixed sorted the problem, thanks!